# Changing the font color & font family of the text on a hamburger menu not working

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am trying to figure out how to change the text on my hamburger bar.  The codes below are attempts on how to change the text and font-family in the hamburger bar.  Each of these attempts seem to only 
change the color of the hamburger bar icon, instead of the dropdown text.

```
.menu-text {
  color: #1E90FF !important;
  font-family: Georgia;
}

.nav-bar ul {
  color: #1E90FF !important;
  font-family: Georgia;
}
```

Comment: Add some context, please.

Comment: can you show me full code

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Materialize before, but just quickly inspected the source of their dropdown menu. It looks like they have the colors coded to the children of the unordered list elements, like so:

```
.dropdown-content li>a, .dropdown-content li>span {
   /* styles here */
}
```

Because of the specificity of their selector, your color definitions would be overridden for the text elements.

I'd recommend inspecting the element using your browser and ensure you are using the most appropriate selector to override their base styles.

Comment: Thank you!  That worked.  All I had to do was change the .dropdown-content to what I have which is .side-nav.  Thanks again @Quantastical !